# string editing in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

```
sh -version
GNU sh, version 1.14.7(1)
```

`cat file`:

> 21/Oct/2013:21:29:29 +0530 10.104.x.x www.google.co.in
>   http://www.google.co.in/ads/user-lists/998935479/?

I have a file with above pattern

```
grep -i http file | awk -F " " '{print $1","$3","$4","$5}'  > file2
```

with above command the output is below

> 21/Oct/2013:21:29:29,10.104.x.x,www.google.co.in,http://www.google.co.in/ads/user-lists/998935479/?

but I want output like below

> 21/Oct/2013,21:29:29,10.104.x.x,www.google.co.in,http://www.google.co.in/ads/user-lists/998935479/?

I want to split date and time in sap-rate values. please help me.

Comment: So, the only difference is the colon after `2013`? Took me a while to find  that...

Comment: yes, suppose to add one more column  to sap rate date and time

Answer (score 1):

Use [sed](http://man.cx/sed):

```
grep -i http test.txt | awk -F " " '{print $1","$3","$4","$5}' | sed 's/:/,/'
```

This is very fragile because it assumes the first `:` needs to become a `,`, but it seems that it will always be so, given your input.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `grep|awk`, if you have chosen awk, it can do all for you:

```
 awk -v OFS="," '/http/{sub(/:/,",",$1);print $1,$3,$4,$5}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "
/[hH][tT][tT][pP]/ {
   s/^\([^ ]\{1,\}\) [^ ]\{1,\} \(.*\)/\1,\2/p
   }" File
```

or

```
sed -n "
/[hH][tT][tT][pP]/ {
   s/ +[0-9]\{1,} /,/p
   }" File
```

you can replace `/[hH][tT][tT][pP]/` with `/${YourVariable}/` 
in this case, create the `[aA]` version of the variable content before in the shell